# The baby in "The Wind"

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wind

In the movie The Wind (2018), whose baby was Emma carrying? We're shown that Lizzy kills Emma, but was this because Lizzy was going crazy or was Emma actually sleeping around with Isaac?

Answer (score 1):

thisisbarry does an extensive review and discussion of The Wind at https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/the-wind-explained-2018-film-ending-explained/

thisisbarry explains why he believes that the baby was Isaac's, but the movie itself doesn't say for sure. It's a fact that the audience isn't supposed to know for sure, since this is, as thisisbarry puts it, an "unreliable narrator" story.

thisisbarry believes that there are enough clues to believe that the baby was Isaac's -- unless those clues were part of Lizzy's madness, which the viewer can't know for sure. thisisbarry's clues are the attraction he sees between the two characters, the diary that says "our baby," the desire to name the baby Isaac, and that Isaac is more concerned with the fact that Emma is dead than the fact that Lizzy is a murderer. You can check the link to see more discussion about it. There's a lot of discussion in the question-and-answer section that comes after his review. thisisbarry's review seems to be the most in-depth and collaborative discussion about this movie, at least that I can find, so you can check out what various viewers think. You can even jump into the discussion yourself if you want.

It's possible that the viewer isn't supposed to know whose baby it is. It's possible that the father of the baby isn't important to the story the writer was telling. What seems to matter in the movie is the madness of the character. Since the character can't know what's real and what isn't, it's possible that the viewer isn't supposed to know, either, to let the viewer be inside of that position of madness.

Comment: Hello! While this answer has potential to be helpful, it lacks some quotes from the article you site to help back it up and there is a lot of repetition from paragraph to paragraph stating the same points over and over that contradict other points that make your answer a bit unclear or unresolved. It comes off like a commentary, more than a more solid answer. If you could edit and clean it up a bit, it might be a better answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

How do we even know any of it was real?
It came from an unreliable narrator, who is clearly suffering from some sort of mental illness.

Would have been good to get some clarity at the end, but as it is.. I'm taking it all as make believe.

She could be in that cabin all alone, abandoned by a family that is ashamed of her illness (which was quite normal, to lock mentally ill family members away) and supplied monthly with food etc.

Even the cabin could be fiction as well, and she's locked up somewhere else and dreaming all of this. Locked up in an hospital or whatever, so she's imagining she lives in a wide open lonely space. The opposite of being locked up in a small room.

I think we could have done with an ending that showed at least some of what was real, and what wasn't real.
An outside perspective from one of the others, if the others even existed that is. Like I said they could all be imaginary just like alot of her other hallucinations.

Comment: Lizzie was with Isaac in the prairie. So he's not part of her imagination. Isaac was witness to an unborn in Emma. So this makes the baby real.